# Как в symfony добавить в конструктор объекты в виде массива?

Tags: php, symfony4

Использую symfony 4.3.11
Создаю TwigFilter

```
class ProcessorExtension extends AbstractExtension
{

    /**
     * @var Driver[]
     */
    private $drivers;

    public function __construct(array $drivers)
    {
        Assert::allIsInstanceOf($drivers, Driver::class);
        $this->drivers = $drivers;
    }

    public function getFilters(): array
    {
        return [
            new TwigFilter("work_processor", [$this, "process"], [ 'is_safe' => ["html"] ])
        ];
    }

    public function process(?string $text): string
    {
        $result = $text;
        foreach ($this->drivers as $driver) {
            $result = $driver->process($text);
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Как видно, в конструктор ProcessorExtension необходимо передать массив объектов типа Driver.

Добавляю в services.yaml сервисы

```
App\Twig\Extension\Work\Driver\:
    resource: '../src/Twig/Extension/Work/Driver/*Driver.php'
    tags: ['app.twig.work_processor.driver']

App\Twig\Extension\Work\ProcessorExtension:
    arguments:
        - !tagged app.twig.work_processor.driver
```

Пробовал по-разному:

```
App\Twig\Extension\Work\ProcessorExtension:
    arguments: [!tagged app.twig.work_processor.driver]
```

Но неизменно получаю ошибку:
**Argument 1 passed to App\Twig\Extension\Work\ProcessorExtension::__construct() must be of the type array, object given, called in /app/var/cache/dev/ContainerViaxSgZ/srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer.php on line 974**

Вопрос: Как добавить в конструктор класса ProcessorExtension объекты в виде массива?

Comment: Покажите как вы передаете этот массив, и желательно dump чтобы увидеть содержимое этого массива

Answer (score 0):

Вам всего лишь нужно прочесть документацию внимательно, там все прозрачно описано, [тык](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/service_container/tags.html). 
(Reference Tagged Services обзац)